# Swift - How to create space between views without cutting off content

Tags: swift, layout

[image]

I have a view controller (B) inside a container (A) and I would like to create some space between the two. Right now, what I have is something like the image on the left, where the padding I created takes up space from B and the content is cut off. The image on the right is the desired outcome, where B would have rounded corners and more space from A.
Here is what the code inside my container class looks like right now:

```
private func configureSampleContainer() {
    sampleController.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear
    sampleController.view.layer.borderWidth = 10
    sampleController.view.clipsToBounds = true
    addChild(sampleController)
    sampleController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.constrain(view: sampleController.view, containerView: sampleContainer)
    sampleController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

configureSampleContainer is called inside viewDidLoad.

View controller B is also being used elsewhere so ideally I wouldn't change anything in B. So how can I achieve this programmatically from my container class A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only thing you'll need to do is add more constraints to your sampleController's view.

Define an extension or just use the body of the extension I created.

```
extension UIViewController {

  func constrain(with margin: CGFloat, to: UIViewController) {
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: to.view.topAnchor, constant: margin).isActive = true
    view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: to.view.leftAnchor, constant: margin).isActive = true
    view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: to.view.rightAnchor, constant: margin).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: to.view.bottomAnchor, constant: margin).isActive = true
  }

}
```

This will be used in your context as such.

```
private func configureSampleContainer() {
  sampleController.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear
  sampleController.view.layer.borderWidth = 10
  sampleController.view.clipsToBounds = true
  addChild(sampleController)
  sampleController.constrain(with: 30, to: view)
  sampleController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the extension, the method signature has `to: UIViewController`, but in your example the method is called `to: view`. 
I tried calling the method with sampleContainer, which is a UIView:

`sampleController.constrain(with: 30, to: sampleContainer)`

But the app crashes with an exception:
'Unable to activate constraint with anchors and because they have no common ancestor. Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies? That's illegal.'

Please let me know if you have any suggestion on how to address this. Thanks!

Comment: I was assuming that configureSampleContainer was a method on a ViewController. You could alter the extension method to instead exist on UIView.